# VMs on same host get same IP

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I would like to create 2 VMs in VirtualBox that have "normal" network interface as my host's. I have set up them with Bridged Adapter but unfortunately they get both the same IP. So I cannot login to any of them. How come they get the same IP?

Comment: Can you login normally when only one of the VMs is started? Are their mac addresses the same?

Comment: yes i've found a conflict on MAC. Regenerating one of them solves! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem described seems to be related to a [DHCP binding the IP to the MAC Address](https://forum.netgate.com/topic/94221/dhcp-how-to-distribute-ip-s-by-mac-address-instead-of-sequentially).
Please, check if both the VMs have the same MAC. If so, generate a new random MAC by clicking the blue icon beside the MAC Address box under the advanced options.

[image: Network Settings]

Once the VMs have different MAC Addresses new IPs should be assined by DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a DHCP server outside of your host machine?  For example a Router.  Bridged Networking assumes that.

Can you switch to NAT temporarily and see if that gives you different IP addresses for each virtual machine.

Comment: i've found a conflict on MAC. Regenerating one of them solves! thanks